# document.readyState on jQuery ready()

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    console.log(document.readyState);
}
```

shows `interactive` in Chrome 33 on Mac. Why not `complete`?

Comment: Works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/AMByF/ . Does the problem **only** cause on Chrome 33 on Mac?

Comment: Are there any resources which might still be loading, even though the ready() function has been called? What do you see in the Network tab in Chrome dev tools? Any files still pending?

Comment: it is ``complete`` in chrome on windows

Comment: From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.readyState   "...."interactive" once it is finished parsing but still loading sub-resources"

Comment: @Anton this is more relevant jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AMByF/1/

Comment: May i ask you why would you need to check for `document.readyState` ?

Comment: @A.Wolff I fire the same function on `ready` and `resize` and want to check inside of the function that DOM is loaded.

Comment: @JasonEvans please post your comment as an answer and I will be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.readyState](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.readyState)

> Returns "loading" while the document is loading, "interactive" once it
>   is finished parsing but still loading sub-resources, and "complete"
>   once it has loaded.

Comment: Wasn't sure what to do here. Technically, I did answer before user3438825, so I've moved my comment to be an answer and see what happens.

Answer (score 3):

From [`document.readyState` at mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.readyState)

> (`document.readyState`) Returns "loading" while the document is loading, *"interactive" once it is finished parsing but still loading sub-resources, and "complete" once it has loaded.*